# C# get images from folder

Tags: c#, image

I have a product with this code: **194578**

There is a folder with a lot of images, the product's main image is **194578.JPG**

There are some other images for the same product that I have to show as details but the thing is, these other images I have no idea of how much I only know they have a letter after the numbers, like:

```
194578A.jpg
194578B.jpg
194578C.jpg
```

and so on, until the max o **194578Z.jpg**

I have the product code, how do I get those detail images?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Change your name from Gerep to [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fgrep) and you should be good to go!  ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) to find files in a directory matching a pattern:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("path/to/directory", prefix + "?.jpg");
```

Comment: how do i generate that prefix automatically? I'm a beginner, this is my first project =)

Comment: Yeap...but how do I add the letters on the number? It is possible to have the 194578A to 194578Z or just 194578A

Comment: @Gerep: You don't have to - that call to `Directory.GetFiles` will look for all files in the directory which start with the code, then have 0 or 1 characters followed by ".jpg". The result is a string array with the filenames in.

Comment: oooo sorry...thanks a lot Jon..as I said, I'm a beginner and had no idea about it =)

Comment: @Lucky: That's not really a related question given the difference in environment. You shouldn't add comments on an answer asking for help on an unrelated question.