# How can we get all files in the Folder using C# for windows 8 Apps

Tags: c#, image, windows-8

I'm very new to windows 8 Application development. I'm trying to get all the images from the folder.

```
StorageFolder statesubFolder = await stateFolder.CreateFolderAsync("multimedia", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
StorageFile imageFiles1 = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("multimedia//" + "*.jpg");

await imageFiles.CopyAsync(statesubFolder, "*.jpg", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

I tried like this:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("ms-appx-web:///multimedia/", "*.jpg");
```

When i'm using like this i'm getting error as " The name Directory does not exits in the current context"

But I'm not getting any images. Can any one suggest to me how I can get all the images from the multimedia folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# get images from folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381410/c-sharp-get-images-from-folder)

Comment: but when i'm implementing its not working getting errors. I'm doing this for windows8 Apps

Comment: Sorry, but "its not working getting errors" is not a useful problem description. If you're "getting errors", what errors are you getting? (Please [edit] your question to add the error information there, including the *exact error message* you're receiving, instead of burying it in the comments.)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to file system operations with WinRT  you can forget what learned with legacy .net Framework. Directory, File etc... are not available.

To get all files in a folder you should just call [GetFilesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227276.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). However it does not support search pattern so you will have to do the extension filtering yourself (but it should not be a big deal).